# Divs are appearing in reverse order

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a simple wrapper, which contains two elements. So I made a wrapper class which has two children. 
The div's children are appearing in a reverse order.

Any ideas what should I do?

Here is my html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="intro">
 <div class="iPhone">
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 float: right;
}

.intro {
 float:left;
 background-size:cover;
}

.iPhone {
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: I removed the floating styles and it's still the same.

Comment: They are not in reverse order (i just tried your code and it works)

Comment: Your HTML looks odd...you haven't closed the divs inside the wrapper.

Comment: Also, position absolute is inconsistent with float...pick one or the other...not both - https://jsfiddle.net/L0sdhoLs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of things..

1. When you use absolute positioning, the property float will be ignored. If you want to position the wrapper use instead left, right, top and bottom properties
2. Don't forget to close your divs, may be some browsers can mess up your code because you did not add a `</div>` tag

I've tested your code and it seems to render alright, intro on the left and iPhone on the right. Take a look a this in your browser (i've added some colours, widths and heights to demonstrate it)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            float: right;
            background-color: red;

            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        .intro {
             float:left;
             background-size:cover;

             background-color: blue;
             width: 50%;
             height: 100%;
        }

        .iPhone {
             float:left;

             background-color: green;
             width: 50%;
             height: 100%;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="intro"></div>
        <div class="iPhone"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot final  tags inside container. If you're using float when you need to use some .clearfix class to parent container that they're displayed correctly.
Add this to wrapper:

```
.clearfix:after {
display: table;
content: "";
clear: both;
}
```